# Programming with OpenGL problems MinGW

Tags: c, eclipse, opengl, codeblocks

I tried on eclipse and got the error "Cannot open output file , Permission denied" when trying to use OpenGL. When I used code::blocks - got the same problems as compiling it by myself at the cmd using `gcc -o <file_name>.exe <file_name>.c`. And all I got was a list full of "undefined reference" to each function appeared in the program taken from OpenGL headers.
That's the small programs - just printing a red square in the middle.

```
#include <GL\gl.h>
#include <GL\glu.h>
#include <GL\glut.h>
#include <GL\freeglut.h>
#include <GL\glext.h>
#include <GL\freeglut_ext.h>
#include <GL\freeglut_std.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <windows.h>

void display()
{
glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
//Draw a red 1x1 square in center
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex2f(-0.5f, -0.5f);    // x, y
glVertex2f( 0.5f, -0.5f);
glVertex2f( 0.5f,  0.5f);
glVertex2f(-0.5f,  0.5f);
glEnd();

glFlush(); //render now
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
glutInit(&argc, argv);                 // Initialize GLUT
glutCreateWindow("OpenGL Setup Test"); // Create a window with the given title
glutInitWindowSize(320, 320);   // Set the window's initial width & height
glutInitWindowPosition(50, 50); // Position the window's initial top-left corner
glutDisplayFunc(display); // Register display callback handler for window re-paint
glutMainLoop();           // Enter the infinitely event-processing loop
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you make sure your PATH environment variable knows where the GL libraries are?

Comment: It knows where MinGW\bin is, I didn't defined more because the configuring and errors in eclipse only said defining where's MinGW\bin

Comment: I ask because if *all* of your GL-defined functions have undefined reference, then it sounds like either your PATH env. variable can't find the libraries or you didn't link them properly.

Comment: where to link them ? I know I can do it manually -lglu32 -lopengl32 but where to link automatically in eclipse ? +I'll first test manually to test it

Comment: Here's what I got - about half less errors when linking this way (manually - CMD):
gcc -o <file>.exe <file>.c -lglu32 -lopengl32
but still some errors in functions as glutCreateMenuWithExit and any functions that starts with glut.

Comment: SUCCESS !!!!!! Just linked freeglut. Thanks everyone anyway - but any idea how to make it automatically linked in eclipse?

Comment: wrt eclipse I have no idea.

Comment: Any recommendations maybe ? In Code::Blocks ? anything ? :P

Comment: I honestly don't know. I use gcc/g++ on the command line, so I've never dealt with linkage in an IDE. I just write makefiles.

Comment: Hmm I wrote a batch command to shorten it :PPPPPP Thank you anyway :)